# Generating arrays using bsxfun with anonymous function and for elementwise subtractions - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization, bsxfun

I have the following code:

```
n = 10000; 
s = 100;
Z = rand(n, 2);
x = rand(s, 1);
y = rand(s, 1);
fun = @(a) exp(a);
```

In principle, the anonymous function `f` can have a different form. I need to create two arrays.

First, I need to create an array of size `n x s x s` with generic elements

```
fun(Z(i, 1) - x(j)) * fun(Z(i, 2) - y(k))
```

where `i=1,...n` while `j,k=1,...,s`. What I can easily do, is to construct matrices using `bsxfun`, e.g.

```
bsxfun(@(x, y) fun(x - y), Z(:, 1), x');
bsxfun(@(x, y) fun(x - y), Z(:, 2), y');
```

But then I would need to combine them into `3D` array by multiplying element-wise each column of those two matrices.

---

In the second step, I need to create an array of size `n x 3 x s x s`, which would look from one side as the following matrix

```
[ones(n, 1), Z(:, 1) - x(i), Z(:, 2) - y(j);]
```

where `i=1,...s`, `j=1,...s`. I could loop over the two extra dimensions with something like

```
A = [ones(n, 1), Z(:, 1) - x(1), Z(:, 2) - y(1)];
for i = 1:s
    for j = 1:s
        A(:, :, i, j) = [ones(n, 1), Z(:, 1) - x(i), Z(:, 2) - y(j);];
    end
end
```

Is there a way to avoid loops?

---

In the third step, suppose that after obtaining array `out1` (output from first step), I want to create a new array `out3` of dimension `n x n x s x s`, which contains the original array `out1` on the main diagonal, i.e. `out3(i,i,s,s) = out1(i, s, s)` and `out3(i,j,s,s)=0` for all `i~=j`. Is there some kind of alternative of `diag` for creating "diagonal arrays"? Alternatively, if I create `n x n x s x s` array of zeros, is there a way to put `out1` on the main diagonal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
exp_Z_x = exp(bsxfun(@minus,Z(:,1),x.')); %//'
exp_Z_y = exp(bsxfun(@minus,Z(:,2),y.')); %//'
out1 = bsxfun(@times,exp_Z_x,permute(exp_Z_y,[1 3 2]));

Z1 = [ones(n,1) Z(:,1) Z(:,2)];
X1 = permute([ zeros(s,1) x zeros(s,1)],[3 2 1]);
Y1 = permute([ zeros(s,1) zeros(s,1) y],[4 2 3 1]);
out2 = bsxfun(@minus,bsxfun(@minus,Z1,X1),Y1);

out3 = zeros(n,n,s,s); %// out3(n,n,s,s) = 0; could be used for performance
out3(bsxfun(@plus,[1:n+1:n*n]',[0:s*s-1]*n*n)) = out1; %//'

%// out1, out2 and out3 are the desired outputs
```

Comment: @Laimond Was a bug there with the second part, a big one. Please check out the edits for the fix!

Comment: I made a mistake. It should be Z(:, 2) in the third column of Z1. Thanks!

Comment: @Laimond Edited! :) Just curious if you don't mind being bothered - How do these solutions compare against your `bsxfun with anonymous functions`? Any runtime comparisons?

Comment: Indeed, it's a very nice speed up. Doing bsxfun with @minus, is more than 50 times faster than bsxfun with anonymous function (I did a separate simulation). I'm very impressed!:) Thank you!

Comment: @Laimond Awesome and thank you for those tests!! Well I had that hunch too and just wanted to strengthen that! :)

Comment: Just one more question:). Suppose that after obtaining array `out1`, I want to create a new array `out3` of dimension `n x n x s x s`, which contains the original array out1 on the main diagonal, i.e. `out3(i,i,s,s) = out1(i, s, s)` and `out3(i,j,s,s)=0` for all `i~=j`. Is there some kind of alternative of `diag` for creating "diagonal arrays"? Alternatively, if I create `n x n x s x s` array of zeros, is there a way to put `out1` on the main diagonal?

Comment: @Laimond Before doing that, you do understand that will create huge `10k x 10k x 100 x 100` array, right? Can your MATLAB handle that?

Comment: I see... Suppose that I can reduce `S` to `20` and `n` can be reduced to `1000`.

Comment: @Laimond Could you add this new stuff at the end of the question?

Comment: I see your point. It should be easier to handle my problem without explicitly defining this new array.

Comment: @Laimond Well I have made the edit, but since this is not mentioned in the question, future readers might get confused. So, just for the sake of syncing, I think making this edit in the question would make sense :) Also, please make sure the edit works for you.

Comment: Thank you for this discussion. It was very insightful! I will try to avoid generating large arrays. You edits seem to work:).

Comment: And thanks for editing the question and showing how to format it properly.