# Matlab function with two vector arguments

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a function defined as follows:

```
@(A,N0,Tb,lambda,p) p.*erfc(1.0./sqrt(N0).*sqrt(Tb).*(A-lambda)).*(1.0./2.0)-erfc(1.0./sqrt(N0).*sqrt(Tb).*(A+lambda)).*(p-1.0).*(1.0./2.0)
```

I have `N0` and `lambda` as vectors. If I pass `N0` as a vector and `lambda` as a scalar, I get a vector output.

For each `lambda`, I want to evaluate the function with the full `N0` vector. (i.e., I want to return an array of vectors instead of just one vector). Is there a way to do this without looping?

Comment: What are `A`, `Tb` and `p`? How do you plan to use the modified vectorized version of the function handle in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume your data is given by:

- `A`, `Tb`, `p` scalar values
- `N0`, `lambda` **column**-vectors.

### Version 1 - (fast and specific to the problem)

As the two vectors you are trying to combine are combined via multiplication, you can make use of linear algebra. If you multiply a column vector by a row vector, you will get the matrix of pairwise products:

```
>> (1:4)'*(10:12)
ans =
    10    11    12
    20    22    24
    30    33    36
    40    44    48
```

So your code would result in:

```
f = @(A,N0,Tb,lambda,p) p*erfc(sqrt(Tb./N0)*(A-lambda).')*0.5 ...
                   +(1-p)*erfc(sqrt(Tb./N0)*(A+lambda).')*0.5
```

### Version 2 - (more general and reusing code)

If your formula were to combine the values by something else than multiplication, you couldn't go with linear algebra. For this there is the marvelous function `bsxfun`, which combines the column and row vectors in a similar way, but you can specify the function to use instead of multiplication. You can use it here in the following way:

Let's call your initial function `f`, you could then define a new function `g`, that handles `lambda` and `N0` pairwise with this:

```
g = @(A,N0,Tb,lambda,p) bsxfun(@(N0,lambda) f(A,N0,Tb,lambda,p), N0, lambda')
```

Comment: Ah there we go.  I was about to modify my post to use `bsxfun`, but you beat me to it.  Nice!

Comment: @rayryeng: You gotta be quick with all of you vectorization-lovers around. ;-)

Comment: Haha I suppose. May the best person win!

Comment: @rayryeng Learning all of Matlab's bells and whistles from you and the crew makes me a winner already!

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm going with version 2.

Comment: The anonymous version of bsxfun isnt that bad as I was assuming it to be earlier. I had experienced some not-so-good performance runtimes with it in the past, here's [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592765/generating-arrays-using-bsxfun-with-anonymous-function-and-for-elementwise-subtr/26593369#comment41803858_26593369)

Comment: @Divakar: I also wasn't expecting it to perform that well! So either this depends strongly on the situation or they might have improved on the routines. Anyway: It certainly means that an anonymous version can be considered if it improves on clarity of the total code.

Comment: Certainly for that and for generalized codes. But, I would certainly time them as well. I just like to time stuffs :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.  You'll need to do a bit of pre-processing before you use your function handle.  I'm going to assume that `N0` and `lambda` are both **column vectors** where `N0` is `M` elements long and `lambda` is `N` elements long.  If you want to create a 2D matrix such that each row is the result of applying a single value of `lambda` while `N0` remains constant, what you'll need to do is make both `N0` and `lambda` a **matrix** such that they are **both** `N x M` long.  `N0` will be **transposed** such that it will be a **row** vector, and stacked row-wise `N` times to create this matrix.  `lambda` will also be `N x M`, where the `lambda` vectors gets stacked column-wise `M` times to create this matrix.

You would then submit these matrices as input into your function handle.  The result would be a `N x M` matrix, where each **column** is the result of applying **one** lambda to the vector `N0`.  As proof of this concept, consider the first part of your function handle:

```
p.*erfc(1.0./sqrt(N0).*sqrt(Tb) ...
```

The result of this step will have `M` identical columns produced from the `erfc` function.  We then multiply this with `(A - lambda)`.  `lambda` will be shaped in such a way where each row reflects a **single** lambda to be applied to every single value of `N0`.  The same can be said about the other side of the equation with `(A + lambda)`.  As such, try doing this:

```
M = numel(N0);
N = numel(lambda);
N0_matrix = repmat(N0.', N, 1);
lambda_matrix = repmat(lambda, 1, M);
f = @(A,N0,Tb,lambda,p) p.*erfc(1.0./sqrt(N0).*sqrt(Tb).*(A-lambda)).*(1.0./2.0)-erfc(1.0./sqrt(N0).*sqrt(Tb).*(A+lambda)).*(p-1.0).*(1.0./2.0);
out = f(A, N0_matrix, Tb, lambda_matrix, p);
```

`out` will be that `N x M` matrix we talked about.

Answer (score 1):

### Some discussion and code

Proposed here is another `bsxfun` based approach tailor-made for the specific function handle used in the problem -

```
%// This could could be reused in the function definition, 
%// so that pre-calulcating it makes sense for performance
f1vals = 1.0./sqrt(N0).*sqrt(Tb);

%// Finally get the output using f1vals and other inputs
out = p.*erfc(bsxfun(@times,f1vals,A - lambda')).*0.5 - ...
                     erfc(bsxfun(@times,f1vals,A + lambda')).*(p-1.0).*0.5;
```

Please note that this approach also assumes `N0` and `lambda` as column-vectors and others as scalars.

### Benchmarking

The proposed solution code was run against [`@knedlsepp's Version -1 solution code`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27587464/3293881) and [@rayryeng's solution code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27587487/3293881) 
for various datasizes. The benchmarking code is listed [**here on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/ZzbZP7). The runtimes obtained on my system were -

1) `N0` and `lambda` of lengths `500`:

```
--------- With Proposed solution
Elapsed time is 0.068731 seconds.
--------- With Knedlsepp Version - 1 solution
Elapsed time is 0.082629 seconds.
--------- With Rayryeng solution
Elapsed time is 0.132094 seconds.
```

2) `N0` and `lambda` of lengths `1000`:

```
--------- With Proposed solution
Elapsed time is 0.220694 seconds.
--------- With Knedlsepp Version - 1 solution
Elapsed time is 0.244323 seconds.
--------- With Rayryeng solution
Elapsed time is 0.334007 seconds.
```

3) `N0` and `lambda` of lengths `3500`:

```
--------- With Proposed solution
Elapsed time is 2.571570 seconds.
--------- With Knedlsepp Version - 1 solution
Elapsed time is 3.009692 seconds.
--------- With Rayryeng solution
Elapsed time is 3.747122 seconds.
```

Comment: It's interesting to see that even though it is not specifically tailored for speed, it still can compete quite well! +1

Comment: @knedlsepp Oh hold on! I must be comparing against your version -1, as that was your faster version. I am updating as we speak! :)

Comment: @knedlsepp Alright, so I have updated the codes and text to make it fair with the runtimes now.

Comment: We could also save some cycles by using: `sqrt(Tb./N0)`.

Comment: @knedlsepp Yeah! That should make it a tad faster!