# Matlab bsxfun - Why does bsxfun fail to work in this case?

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization, bsxfun

I have a binary function roughly looks like

```
func=@(i,j)exp(-32*(i-j)^2);
```

with mesh as follows

```
[X Y]=meshgrid(-10:.1:10);
```

Strangely, `arrayfun` produces the right result while `bsxfun` would produce entries that are `Inf`.

```
an1=arrayfun(func,X,Y);
an2=bsxfun(func,X,Y);

>> max(max(abs(an1-an2)))
ans = 
     Inf
```

Why?

---

EDIT: now that the question is resolved. I am including some benchmark data to facilitate the discussion on efficiency with `bsxfun`

Assuming the grid is already produced with

```
[X Y]=meshgrid(Grid.partition);
func=@(i,j)exp(-32*(i-j).^2);
```

(I intend to re-use the grid many times in various places.)

Timing the nested named functions approach.

```
>> tic;for i=1:1000;temp3=exp(-32*bsxfun(@minus,Grid.partition.',Grid.partition).^2);end;toc,clear temp
Elapsed time is 1.473543 seconds.
>> tic;for i=1:1000;temp3=exp(-32*bsxfun(@minus,Grid.partition.',Grid.partition).^2);end;toc,clear temp
Elapsed time is 1.497116 seconds.
>> tic;for i=1:1000;temp3=exp(-32*bsxfun(@minus,Grid.partition.',Grid.partition).^2);end;toc,clear temp
Elapsed time is 1.816970 seconds.
```

Timing the anonymous function approach

```
>> tic;for i=1:1000;temp=bsxfun(func,X,Y);end;toc,clear temp
Elapsed time is 1.134980 seconds.
>> tic;for i=1:1000;temp=bsxfun(func,X,Y);end;toc,clear temp
Elapsed time is 1.171421 seconds.
>> tic;for i=1:1000;temp=bsxfun(func,X,Y);end;toc,clear temp
Elapsed time is 1.180998 seconds.
```

One can see that the anonymous function approach is faster than the nested function approach (excluding the time on `meshgrid`).

If the time on `meshgrid` is included,

```
>> tic;[X Y]=meshgrid(Grid.partition);for i=1:1000;temp=bsxfun(func,X,Y);end;toc,clear X Y temp
Elapsed time is 1.965701 seconds.
>> tic;[X Y]=meshgrid(Grid.partition);for i=1:1000;temp=bsxfun(func,X,Y);end;toc,clear X Y temp
Elapsed time is 1.249637 seconds.
>> tic;[X Y]=meshgrid(Grid.partition);for i=1:1000;temp=bsxfun(func,X,Y);end;toc,clear X Y temp
Elapsed time is 1.208296 seconds.
```

Hard to say...

Comment: Well, as also pointed out by Luis, `meshgrid` must also be inside the tic-tocs of  anonymous function version of `bsxfun`, right? `bsxfun(@minus` approach does both the `meshgrid` part and the *`evalauation of the function* part in one go.

Comment: I added the data for including `meshgrid` time. They are comparable.

Comment: They do look comparable! Thanks for taking time to put all these!

Comment: Thank YOU!! I am happy for learning all these. On a side note, I used to produce a meshgrid of indices and apply my binary function like `@(i,j)exp(-32*partition(i)-partition(j))^2`. That was slow. Not doing that anymore!

Comment: So, going with the built-in `@minus`? Awesome!

Comment: If I am not re-using the meshgrid. Definitely using build-in. In the case the meshgrid is re-used many times. I think I'll use anonymous. :)

Comment: That strategy makes sense, compact and efficient!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acording to the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), when you call `bsxfun` with an arbitrary function `func`,

> `func`must be able to accept as input either two column vectors of the same size, or one column vector and one scalar, and return as output a column vector of the same size as the input(s).

Your function does not fulfill that. To correct it, replace `^` by `.^`:

```
func=@(i,j)exp(-32*(i-j).^2);
```

Anyway, instead of your function you could use one of `bsxfun`'s built-in functions (see [@Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626677/2586922)). That way you avoid `meshgrid`, and the code will probably be faster.

Comment: Yup, that must be the syntax for it!

Comment: Tested. And that is the reason. Thank you!

Comment: As for speed, I don't think named functions are faster. (Tested in this case. The correct `func` is faster. I have also experienced in other scenarios that nested functions as suggested by Divakar is less efficient.)

Comment: @Argyll But you at least avoid `meshgrid`. It should be faster. Or that's what I thought

Comment: @Argyll Well I highly doubt that. I worked with annonym. func with `bsxfun` on a case before, [here are the runtimes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592765/generating-arrays-using-bsxfun-with-anonymous-function-and-for-elementwise-subtr/26593369#comment41803858_26593369). Also as Luis said you would be avoiding `meshgrid` there.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of that way of using `Anonymous Functions` with `bsxfun`, you could do something like this for a more efficient usage of `bsxfun` -

```
arr1 = -10:.1:10
an2 = exp(-32*bsxfun(@minus,arr1.',arr1).^2)
```

---

### Benchmarking

Trying to clarify on OP's runtime comments here to compare bsxfun's Anonymous Functions capabilities against the built-in `@minus` with some benchmarking.

**Benchmarking code**

```
func=@(i,j)exp(-32.*(i-j).^2);

num_iter = 1000;

%// Warm up tic/toc.
for k = 1:100000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end

disp('---------------------------- Using Anonymous Functions with bsxfun')
tic
for iter = 1:num_iter
    [X Y]=meshgrid(-10:.1:10);
    an2=bsxfun(func,X,Y);
end
toc, clear X Y an2

disp('---------------------------- Using bsxfuns built-in "@minus"')
tic
for iter = 1:num_iter
    arr1 = -10:.1:10;
    an2 = exp(-32*bsxfun(@minus,arr1',arr1).^2);
end
toc
```

**Runtimes**

```
---------------------------- Using Anonymous Functions with bsxfun
Elapsed time is 0.241312 seconds.
---------------------------- Using bsxfuns built-in "@minus"
Elapsed time is 0.221555 seconds.
```

Comment: Nested functions like this is not more efficient. (The corrected `func` is faster.) But thank you for the `arr1.',arr1` syntax. I would very much love to avoid `meshgrid`.

Comment: @Argyll What datasize did you test out on?

Comment: Same as in the example. 201. Anonymous is about 1.5x faster excluding the time on `meshgrid`.

Comment: @Argyll Check out the benchmarking code added just now, and see how it performs at your end?

Comment: `arrayfun` is always that much slower. Try `bsxfun` with the anonymous function?

Comment: @Argyll Ops sorry, let me add that!

Comment: @Argyll Why do you exclude `meshgrid`? The `@minus` approach includes the equivalent part to `meshgrid`

Comment: Ah, I see. Although I intended to reuse the produced grid many times. That's why I excluded it.